# PHP - Erro na função preg_match

Tags: php

Boa Tarde Pessoal!

Tenho encontrado um pouco de dificuldade em arrumar este erro abaixo na versão do PHP 7 quando submeto o formulário utilizando um script de UPLOAD, a imagem é salva corretamente na pasta e inserida no banco, mas quando a página retorna para ela mesma, vem com a mensagem:

1º Tenho o formulário cadastra_anuncio.php com o formulário:

```
if(@$_POST["enviar"]){

   if(@$_FILES["foto"]["name"] == true){
        $foto_form = $_FILES["foto"];
        include_once ("config/upload.php");
        $foto_old = upload_xy ($foto_form, $foto_form, 360, 280);
        $thumb_old = upload_xy ($foto_form, $foto_form, 140, 90);
        $nome_foto = md5(uniqid(time()));
        manipulacao_img($nome_foto, $thumb_old, $foto_old);
        $foto = $nome_foto . '.jpg';
        $thumb = $nome_foto . '_thumb.jpg';
    }
    $id_bandeira = strip_tags($_POST["bandeira"]);
    $id_categoria = strip_tags($_POST["categoria"]);

    $nome = strip_tags($_POST["nome"]);
    $email = strip_tags($_POST["email"]);
    $categoria = strip_tags($_POST["categoria"]);
    $descricao = str_replace("\r\n", "<br/>", strip_tags($_POST["descricao"]));
    $bandeira = strip_tags($_POST["bandeira"]);
    $data = date("Y-m-d");

    @mysqli_query($link,"INSERT INTO anuncios (ID_BANDEIRA, ID_CATEGORIA, nome, email, categoria, descricao, bandeira, data, foto, thumb, status) VALUES ('$id_bandeira','$id_categoria','$nome', '$email', '$categoria', '$descricao', '$bandeira', '$data', '$foto', '$thumb', 'Inativo')");

}
```

2º O script chama o upload.php que faz o processo e dentro dele mesmo tem um require chamando class.upload.php e o erro é exatamente na linha 2249:

```
if(!preg_match('\.([^\.]*$)', $this->file_src_name, $extension)){
```

> Warning: preg_match(): Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash
>   in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\dashboard\Aplicativos\Classificados\config\class.upload.php
>   on line 2249

Gostaria de saber o que preciso acertar nessa expressão regular, não estou conseguindo arrumar este item, gostaria do auxilio de vocês amigos, obrigado.

Comment: Tente delimitar sua expressão regular com barra invertida, assim `if(!preg_match('/\.([^\.]*$)/', $this->file_src_name, $extension)){...`

Comment: Obrigado abfurlan, deu certo a alteração.

Comment: Vou postar como resposta.

Answer (score 2):

Você precisa delimitar sua expressão regular com barras invertidas.

Onde está:

```
if(!preg_match('\.([^\.]*$)', $this->file_src_name, $extension)){...
```

Troque por:

```
if(!preg_match('/\.([^\.]*$)/', $this->file_src_name, $extension)){...
```